# Termite launches programs in a small area of instead of taking up whole window when using '-e'

Tags: i3, termite

When running a command in termite (cmatrix works well to demonstrate this), only part of the window is used.

The image below shows launching from fish, but just launching from termite, e.g. `termite -e cmatrix` has the same effect. This can also be demonstrated with text, e.g `termite -e 'man man'`, `termite -e nvim`, et cetera. Running normally, i.e just typing the command, works fine, filling the window with text

[image: Doesn't take up full window]

If it's relevant, I'm using i3 on Manjaro ARM aarch64.